# add action in class not running, always return 0

Tags: ajax, wordpress, class

I'm trying to run an ajax action in my custom class but it seems to not call at all the action (class method actually). The scripts are well loaded, means the class is included and instanciated.

```
class Myclass {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_loadmore', array( $this, 'loadmore' ) );
        add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', array( $this, 'loadmore' ) );

    }

    public function scripts() {

        wp_register_script( 'filter', 'assets/js/filter.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'filter' );
        wp_localize_script( 'filter', 'filter', array(
            'ajaxurl'        => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
            'loadmore_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'loadmore_nonce' )
        ) );

    }

    public function loadmore() {

        if ( ! check_ajax_referer( 'loadmore_nonce', 'loadmore_nonce', false ) )
            exit;

        @header( 'Content-Type: application/json' );
        echo json_encode( array(
            'foo' => 'bar'
        ) );
        exit;


    }

}
```

In my JS file I wrote the following:

```
$('#loadmore a').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: filter.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'loadmore_nonce': filter.loadmore_nonce
        },
        success: function (response) {

            console.log(response);

        }
    });

});
```

The AJAX success callback always returns 0

> And the 0 comes from die('0'); at the end of the admin-ajax.php file

Comment: typo here: `'foo' => 'bar`  <-- missing closing single quote

Comment: It's not the problem, I miss it when rewriting the code here.

Comment: And I also checked the debug log file, and no errors appear

Comment: Is the nonce being passed correctly?  What if you comment out the `check_ajax_referer` call for testing?

Comment: I did and still returning 0

Comment: Try changing `exit` to `die()` or `wp_die() `

Comment: `die` and `exit` are equivalent - http://php.net/manual/en/function.die.php

Comment: its returning something, it just might not be from the wp ajax file, echo out the ajax url you have above and just stick that into your ajax function to check.

Comment: I think the problem is not in the loadmore() method, because I produce a voluntary error in it and is does not appear in my debug log file.

Comment: @hobo wordpress [handles it differently](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)

Comment: @David the url is correct

Comment: I'm on SSL, maybe it differs but I don't think so

Comment: @fredmat have you checked the js file being outputted? I don't use localize script or register script so someone else may be able to answer more definitively on why this happens, but there seems to be a timing issue where the url is not passed. As i said earlier its returning something, but not the function you want, hence the question about the url and obviously assuming you initialize myclass within functions.php

Comment: @M.Doye point taken - `wp_die()` is different.  I was just saying `die` and `exit` were the same thing, so changing `exit` to `die` (one possibility you suggested) wouldn't have made a difference

Comment: @fredmat the 0 can come different urls other than `ajax.php?yourfunction` . If the correct url was passed, it would be impossible for 0 to be outputted unless `json_encode` or `header` (btw not required) returned it. I've actually answered this for you, if you provide your url ill show you why.

Comment: Sorry, what url you want?

Comment: if you give me a link to your page?

Comment: I'm on localhost, how will you see where it comes from can you explain please? I check it and the 0 comes from the latest die() in admin-Ajax.php

Comment: ah i cant if you are local host, but view the source code in your browser and view filter.js. You'll see what url the browser trys to visit for ajax

Comment: It's not a url problem, the problem is that the action is not fired

Comment: Ok I finally got it! The problem was that I instantiated the class in index.php Now I did it in my PHP class file and it works. Of course when using ajax, index.php is not loaded, so logical :)